# Mongoose schema with object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, body-parser

I try to fill a document in MongoDB with NodeJS, consequently I created a Schema and a post req.

```
var gameSchema = new Schema({
       title: String,
        developer: {
            name: String,
            email: String
        },
        isBroadcasted: Boolean
    });
```

So **I want to populate this schema thanks to a req.**

```
router.post('/android', auth, function(req, res){
    // Create a new instance of the Game model
    var game = new Game();
        game.title = req.body.title;

game.developer.name = req.body.developer.name;
game.developer.email = req.body.developer.email;
```

[image]

But, when I run it there is an error message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" but **I don't understand why because developer.name exists.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the error is not referring to `game.developer.name` but to `req.body.developer.name`.
Try changing your line to

```
game.developer.name = req.body['developer.name']
```

as your parameter `developer.name` is parsed as string, not as nested object.